# List html5 localstorage data across all sources

Tags: html, local-storage

Is it possible to list out all localstorage data across all sources stored locally in client browser?

I know that cross site scripting(XSS) can get/modify localstorage data for a different source. For that it needs to know the source url of the other site - so if the XSS is not aware of source site can it still find out list and alter cross site localstorage data.

My idea is to save data in a localstorage and attach it to a random source and source will infact be the key for client. So that based on that key I can get back data from the specific source in locastorage. The whole idea is the prevent other sites to get access to this persistent data.

Comment: Interesting concept but I'm pretty sure you can't request the local storage of another site directly (ie. using localStorage). But I could imagine performing an ajax request from site a of a js script on site b which returns the key data from site b. Hmmm, I'll give it a whirl. An alternative might include pulling data from cloud storage by unique id (which could be an encrypted json file).

Answer (score 2):

window.localStorage.key is the solution.
Example:

```
/* use high programming standards!! */
var i = 0, //i is standing for int
    oJson = {}, //o is standing for object
    sKey; //s is standing for string
while ((sKey = window.localStorage.key(i))) {
    oJson[sKey] = window.localStorage.getItem(sKey);
    i++;
}
console.log(oJson);
```